# Using grid_terrain on a LAScatalog, when the first tile (chunk) has no ground points

Tags: lidr

I am getting an error of `"r: No ground points found. Impossible to compute a DTM."` when running `grid_terrain` on a catalog. I think it is because my first tile is all water. Is there an option in LAScatalog to skip chunks based on class?

Comment: If the tile is full of **classified** water update to [v2.2.0](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/releases/tag/v2.2.0). This case is now handled in `lidR`.

Comment: Thank you! I was using 2.1.4 so I will upgrade now.

Comment: I upgraded to v2.2.0, but it did not work for me unfortunately. In my case it does not make sense to include that tile at all so I have removed it. (note: in testing I did alter the file order to force the water tile to 2nd place in processing but was still unsuccessful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `lidR v2.2.0` you have at least four options for your specific case.

1. The computation of a digital terrain model now considers points classified as water like ground points. So you should not encounter troubles if your water is classified. According to your comment I guess it is not.
2. You also have the possibility to flag some tiles that won't be processed. These files are not removed, they are used to load the buffer of the neighboring processed files. You can do it interactively with `catalog_select()` or manually adding a column named `processed` into the `LAScatalog`.

   ```r
   ctg <- catalog_select(ctg, method = "flag_unprocessed")
   ```
3. Indeed as you mentioned in comment you can simply remove the file from the catalog

   ```r
   ctg <- ctg[-1,]
   ```
4. You can bypass errors. I discourage this because if you have another error in another tile it will be bypassed as well without message.

   ```r
   opt_stop_early(ctg) <- FALSE
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I've been using lidR for several weeks and looking forward to becoming more proficient at it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when normalizing some data. I found my way around using `catalog_apply` and a simple `if else`.

```r
wd = "set your working directory"
ctg <- readLAScatalog(paste(wd,"data/",sep = ""), progress = TRUE)

ground_filter = function(chunk)
{
  las = readLAS(chunk)
  if (is.empty(las)) return(NULL)

  ground <- lasfilter(las, Classification == 2)               #filters ground points for each chunk              

  if (is.empty(ground))                                       #if no ground points are found returns NULL
    return(NULL)

  terrain <- grid_terrain(las, res= 1, tin())
  bbox <- raster::extent(chunk)
  terrain <- raster::crop(terrain, bbox)
  return(terrain)                                             #if ground points are found returns terrain
}

opt_chunk_buffer(ctg_0) <- 30                                 #needs to be > 0 to avoid edge artifacts
opt_output_files(ctg_0) <- paste(wd, "*_dtm", sep = "")       #export in directory

DTM <- catalog_sapply(ctg_0, ground_filter)
plot_dtm3d(DTM)
```

It might take longer because it first needs to filter the ground points but is convenient if you need to make a code that doesn´t need to stop (as `catalog_select` where you need to actually select files by hand). On the other hand, `opt_stop_early` bypasses files withouth ground points but might bypass other errors, as @JRR says. This code will skip those files with no ground points but will warn you of other errors.

Comment: This is a valid code, but a buffer of 0.5 is definitively too small.